# How to append alpha characters in a spreadsheet (google sheets)?

Tags: google-sheets, append, google-sheets-formula

I have a string: "region" in a cell. I would like to have a column automatically populate with:

regionA
regionB
regionC
regionD

I have found that by using "char(row(A65)" and then fill down I can auto populate alpha characters.

This works:
=concatenate(B12, char(row(A65)))

(b12 has the "region" string)

But when I do fill down it not only increments the A65 but also increments B12.

How do I have it only increment one part of this function?

I'm also open to other ways of doing this, anything that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a $ before a part of the range, that part stays fixed or static.
So either

```
=concatenate(B$12, char(row(A65)))
```

or

```
=concatenate($B$12, char(row(A65)))
```

can be dragged down, and the B12 won't change.  `$B$12` could also be dragged sideways without changing.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(B12&CHAR(SEQUENCE(4)+64))
```

The '4' will determine how many rows you are spilling down. Obviously this works up to 'Z'.

If you want to extend this further then try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(B12&REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(1,SEQUENCE(100),4),"\D+"))
```

The '100' will determine the amount of rows you spill down.

Comment: sweet! this is another solution!

Comment: @dustycaviar, you are quite welcome. I edited and included an option that will go beyond 'Z'.